# Shorten bottom border length

Tags: html, css

How can I shorten the length of this bottom border, so it starts at the beginning of the "M" and ends at the end of the "t"?[image]

```css
table {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
thead {
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;   
}
td,th {
    padding: .5em 1em;
    text-align: center;
}
tbody:before {
    /* This doesn't work because of border-collapse */
    line-height:1em;
    content:".";
    color:white; /* bacground color */
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Model</th>
                            <th scope="col">Horsepower</th>
                            <th scope="col">Max Dig Depth</th>
                            <th scope="col">Operating Weight</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th>A900</th>
                            <th>129 HP</th>
                            <th>19'</th>
                            <th>41,900 lb</th>
                        </tr>
                        
                        <tr>
                            <th>A900</th>
                            <th>A900</th>
                            <th>A900</th>
                            <th>A900</th>
                        </tr>
                        
                        <tr>
                            <th>A900</th>
                            <th>A900</th>
                            <th>A900</th>
                            <th>A900</th>
                        </tr>
                        
                        <tr>
                            <th>A900</th>
                            <th>A900</th>
                            <th>A900</th>
                            <th>A900</th>
                        </tr>
                        
                        <tr>
                            <th>A900</th>
                            <th>A900</th>
                            <th>A900</th>
                            <th>A900</th>
                        </tr>
                        
                        <tr>
                            <th>A900</th>
                            <th>A900</th>
                            <th>A900</th>
                            <th>A900</th>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    
                </table>
                </body>
                <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<html>
```

I made it into a code snippet, hopefully this makes your life easier. As you can see, I can not shorten the length of the border bottom. If you need anything else, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: You could either set the margin/padding on the sides to 0 so the container borders will start exactly where 'M' and 'T' are. Another approach is to do it with a span or an hr instead of a border-bottom. Sharing your full code would be helpful.

Comment: There is an actual sample... Also, I have tried margin/padding to 0, it did nothing. I also tried a span HR, didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to get the desired effect, is to set the width of all cells in the first and the last column to a width that corresponds to the width of the text in your header, and to set the left and right padding of any cell to 0.

A demo :

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

thead {
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

td,th {
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  text-align: center;
}

tbody::before {
/* This doesn't work because of border-collapse */
  line-height: 1em;
  content: ".";
  color: white; /* bacground color */
  display: block;
}

.first {
  width: 45px;
}

.last {
  width: 125px;
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="first">Model</th>
    <th>Horsepower</th>
    <th>Max Dig Depth</th>
    <th class="last">Operating Weight</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="first">A900</td>
    <td>A900</td>
    <td>A900</td>
    <td class="last">A900</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="first">A900</td>
    <td>A900</td>
    <td>A900</td>
    <td class="last">A900</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="first">A900</td>
    <td>A900</td>
    <td>A900</td>
    <td class="last">A900</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple woy to do this is using a div as the line in a way that the div dont disturb the flow, something like this:

```
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">

  </div>
</div>

.div1 {
  position: relative;
}
.div2 {
  position: Absolute;
  width: 90%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: black;
}
```